# Why is the margin of this middle element overlapping with the top ones but not the bottom ones?

Tags: html, css

[image]

This is a simple form featuring columns and input elements:

Code Snippet:

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}

input {
  color: #343642;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #ccc;
  border-top-color: darken(#ccc, 20%);
  border-style: solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  max-width: 1230px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.col-12 {
  margin: 20px 10px;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
}

.col-6 {
  margin: 20px 10px;
  float: left;
  width: calc(50% - 20px);
}

.col-4 {
  margin: 20px 10px;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% / 3 - 20px);
}

.btn {
  background: #343642;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif: font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #343642;
  border-bottom-color: darken(#343642, 20%);
  border-style: solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <h2>Another example</h2>
    <p>This is some example</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <label>First name</label>
    <input type="text" value=""></input>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <label>Last name</label>
    <input type="text" value=""></input>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <label>Message</label>
    <input type="text" value=""></input>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <label>Message</label>
    <input type="text" value=""></input>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <label>Message</label>
    <input type="text" value=""></input>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <label>Message</label>
    <input type="text" value=""></input>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <button class="btn">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

For some reason the margin of **Message** in the middle overlaps with the margin of **First name** and **Last name** but doesn't overlap with the margin of the three **Message** below (you can see the distance is bigger).

Why is this? And how to fix it?

Comment: Pls use https://jsfiddle.net/ or similar to post your code

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect your new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a separate div for each row, currently everything is in the same row.

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-12">
   <h2>Another example</h2>
   <p>This is some example</p>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <label>First name</label>
    <input type="text" value=""/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <label>Last name</label>
    <input type="text" value=""/>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <label>Message</label>
    <input type="text" value=""/>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">
    <label>Message</label>
    <input type="text" value=""/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <label>Message</label>
    <input type="text" value=""/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <label>Message</label>
    <input type="text" value=""/>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12">
    <button class="btn">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's cause your three Messages below are `float`.

> Margins of floating and absolutely positioned elements never collapse.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing.

To solve the problem, you need to put all your rows in different `<div class="row">` and add a clearfix to the `row` class.

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
}

input {
  color: #343642;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #ccc;
  border-top-color: darken(#ccc, 20%);
  border-style: solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.row {
  max-width: 1230px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

/* The clearfix */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.col-12 {
  margin: 20px 10px;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
}

.col-6 {
  margin: 20px 10px;
  float: left;
  width: calc(50% - 20px);
}

.col-4 {
  margin: 20px 10px;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% / 3 - 20px);
}

.btn {
  background: #343642;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif: font-size: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #343642;
  border-bottom-color: darken(#343642, 20%);
  border-style: solid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <h2>Another example</h2>
    <p>This is some example</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    <label>First name</label>
    <input type="text" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-6">
    <label>Last name</label>
    <input type="text" value="">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <label>Message</label>
    <input type="text" value="">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-4">
    <label>Message</label>
    <input type="text" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <label>Message</label>
    <input type="text" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <label>Message</label>
    <input type="text" value="">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <button class="btn">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```